# Do the different observed Type Ia supernovae have similar explosion energy?

Tags: astrophysics, stars, observational-astronomy, supernova

I have been trying to read about the energetics of observed supernovae for some time.  And while the observed core-collapse supernovae have many scientific papers about them trying to estimate the energy released in different evemts like [this one](http://www.google.com.eg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fauthors.library.caltech.edu%2F17070%2F1%2FHunter2009p6675Astron_Astrophys.pdf&ei=3FoQVILEMM_Q7AbLsID4Dg&usg=AFQjCNGK_ET25PeBYFMeTT1kK86cePr2Nw&sig2=NSyXAFWUTJaEl7Sev-0JIw&bvm=bv.74649129,d.ZGU&cad=rja), I couldn't find similar reports for Type Ia SNe telling how much energy was actually released.

All I could find about energy estimates for Type Ia SNe were different model of detonation and they are very close in the numbers they compute. So, is this lack of Type Ia SNe energetics because they are essentially the same and only one model can be applied to all of them ?
I know Type Ia SN is the result of a thermonuclear runaway in a WD with a Chandrasekhar mass limit, so they should actually produce the same amount of kinetic energy for the ejecta. So is it true that all Type Ia supernovae observed share have similar released energy ?

PS : I am concerned about kinetic energy more than optical and light curves, so the mass of the Ni produced and the luminosity is not important for me here.

Comment: As far as I know, they are the same within a factor of order 1.

Comment: @KyleKanos, so has there been actual observations of them with ~$10^{51}$ ergs in KE of ejecta as those models suggest ?

Comment: The [table in the Supernova wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova#Light_curves) (you'll have to scroll down from the link) shows exactly what I said. There's two links at the top of the table that might indicate *how* these have been observed (because on that aspect, I'm not familiar)

Comment: @AbanobEbrahim, are you interested in the total energy, or just kinetic energy?